# Translated string resources in a framework are not used by the app that imports the framework in Xcode

Tags: string, xcode, frameworks, resources, translation

I have a cross platform (iOS, watchOS and macOS) app. So I created a framework in Xcode and put the share files, the source code that works in all platform, into the framework.

Then I translated them. The app works fine. The only issue is that the translated string resources in the framework are never used by the app.

If I copy the content of the string resources out of the framework and insert them in to the app's string resources, it works. But I don't think it is a good idea to do things in that way.

Any idea on how to making the app use the string resources in the framework directly?

Is this on purpose or it is a bug that I should file to Apple?

Xcode 9.1 (9B55), macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 (17B48)
Swift 4.0.2

A sample project can be found here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6bdp28rmk9rxii/Framework%20Translation%20Issue.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `NSLocalizedString` in a framework must tell the bundle of the framework explicitly. Or the app that calls the framework will use main bundle to find the localization resources.

```
NSLocalizedString("Test", tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, comment: "Test")
```

You can use either `init(for: AnyClass)` or `allFrameworks: [Bundle]` with a filter to get the framework's bundle.

You must not use the id of the bundle directly, unless your are sure it is only fixed to one platform and won't be changed in future.